# Xcode 5, breakpoints in unit test not getting hit

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode5, breakpoints

This one is driving me nuts. Xcode 5 recently started to ignore my breakpoints in my unit tests.  I promise this was working before.  I also promise I have no idea what I changed to cause this behavior, it was working 30 minutes ago and now it is not.

I click on the test navigator and click the play button next to one of my tests.  I did not setup anything to get breakpoints to work and they worked by default, somehow they do not work anymore.

When I hit the play button the tests run and success but breakpoints are not getting hit.

power on test: yes I did verify they are active (dark blue).

Ideas?

Comment: Ok I did make a change.  I updated to using SenTestingKit.  as soon as I switched away from XCTestCase I stopped hitting my breakpoints.

Comment: Newbie, so not even sure what the difference is between the two frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your tests are being ran? If you are switching you need to update the "Wrapper Extension" to xctest. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161332/3096507.