# Unit test not running on IOS swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I'm implementing unit test in Xcode 13 (13A233). I wrote simple test but my xcode fails running test on this project. On other projects it's running fine. It produces an error

> Assertions: System: Test runner never began executing tests after launching. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MunchON-eeidlzwuounsfvbrmieuosqzpsih/Logs/Test/Test-MunchON (Staging)-2021.10.05_11-35-54-+0500.xcresult

I'm unable to resolve this issue. Other questions that i have checked already:

- http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/
- [Xcode 4.2, can't run unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632254/xcode-4-2-cant-run-unit-test)
- [OCUnit tests not running / not being found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608484/ocunit-tests-not-running-not-being-found)
- [OCUnit test cases not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672616/ocunit-test-cases-not-running)

Comment: Reboot your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting DerivedData

1. Open Xcode > Preferences > Locations
2. Click on the arrow to open DerivedData folder
3. Delete all from DerivedData folder
4. Reopen Xcode project

P.S. DerivedData contains cached data such that indexed files etc

FYI It is safe

Comment: This saved me many times because Xcode always break things a part when caching is the one who cause the problem

Comment: it did not help. Can you please suggest another way

Comment: Same issue, rebooted and everything, but it's stuck on Testing.... The testing navigator does not show the tests like it used to in previous XCode version (I'm also now in v13). I tried updateing the Quick pod to v4 but same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by checking the "Allow testing Host Application APIs" option in the test target.

Answer (score 0):

## More information may be helpful.

@aqib-javed
How are you running tests (on which device, iOS version)
Plus do you use Cocoapods?
I had the same issue with one pod in the Cocoapods.
I can recommend removing pod by pod if possible.